# Otorgar o restringir permisos a rutas por medio de roles en Spring Security en Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, users-roles

Buen día a todos,
Tengo una aplicación en Spring Boot en la cual implementé Spring Security.
He logrado iniciar sesión y tener acceso a todas las rutas una vez logeado, y tambien restricción a todas las rutas cuando no se ha iniciado sesión.
En mi sistema tengo una relación de Usuarios -> Roles -> Roles_Menu y Menu como se aprecia en la siguiente imagen:

[image: he añadido los campos adicionales requeridos para User por spring Security]

Quisiera saber si es posible otorgar los permisos a cada rol solo a las rutas que están registradas en base de datos.

Apesar de que en la implementación de Spring Security se incluyen un List de rutas por cada usuario, esto no hace ninguna restricción a las rutas cuyo acceso no se vé reflejado en dicha lista.

Aquí el detalle de mi código:

**Esta es mi clase Usuario**

```
package com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

/**
 *
 * @author ALEJO
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "document")
    private long document;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "second_name")
    private String secondName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "second_surname")
    private String secondSurname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2,max=10) 
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private short state;

    @JoinColumn(name="profile_id")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Profile.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Profile profile;


    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(Integer id, long document, String firstName, String surname, String username, String password,
            short state) {
        this.id = id;
        this.document = document;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.userName = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.state = state;
    }



    public User(@NotNull @Size(min = 2, max = 10) String userName, @NotNull String password) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(long document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getSecondSurname() {
        return secondSurname;
    }

    public void setSecondSurname(String secondSurname) {
        this.secondSurname = secondSurname;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String username) {
        this.userName = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public short getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(short state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", document=" + document + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", secondName=" + secondName
                + ", surname=" + surname + ", secondSurname=" + secondSurname + ", userName=" + userName + ", email="
                + email + ", password=" + password + ", state=" + state + ", profile=" + profile + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Esta es la Clase Perfil (o ROL)**

```
package com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name="profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="profile")
    private List<User> users;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="profileId")
    private List<ProfileMenu> profileMenus;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Transient
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    @Transient
    public List<ProfileMenu> getProfileMenus() {
        return profileMenus;
    }

    public void setProfileMenus(List<ProfileMenu> profileMenus) {
        this.profileMenus = profileMenus;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profile [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", users=" + users + "]";
    }   
}
```

**Esta es la clase Menu**

```
package com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class Menu {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;
    @Column(name = "icon")
    private String icon;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "menus")
    private List<ProfileMenu> profileMenu;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<ProfileMenu> getProfileMenu() {
        return profileMenu;
    }

    public void setProfileMenu(List<ProfileMenu> profileMenu) {
        this.profileMenu = profileMenu;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Menu [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", url=" + url + ", icon=" + icon + ", profileMenu=" + profileMenu
                + "]";
    }

}
```

**Y esta es la clase que relaciona el ROL con el Menu**

```
package com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="profile_menu")
public class ProfileMenu {


    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Profile.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="profile_id")
    private Profile profileId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=Menu.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="menu_id")
    private Menu menus;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Profile getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }
    public void setProfileId(Profile profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }
    public Menu getMenus() {
        return menus;
    }
    public void setMenus(Menu menus) {
        this.menus = menus;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProfileMenu [id=" + id + ", profileId=" + profileId + ", menus=" + menus + "]";
    }   
}
```

**Esta es la configuración de mi tabla Usuario con Spring Security**

```
package com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.service.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.entity.User;
import com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.repository.UserRepository;

@Service("UserServiceSecurity")
public class UserServiceSecurity implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("UserRepository")
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        user.getProfile().getProfileMenus().stream().forEach((x) -> {
            auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(x.getMenus().getUrl()));
            //System.out.println(x.getMenus().getUrl());
        });
        return userBuiler(user, auths);
    }

    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userBuiler(User user,
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
                authorities);
    }
}
```

**Esta es la configuración de Spring Security por http, de acuerdo a la documentación oficial**

```
package com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("UserServiceSecurity")
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void ConfigureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/inicio").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**","/imgs/**","/css/**","/js/**","/fonts/**","/favicon.ico").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .loginPage("/inicio")           
            .failureUrl("/inicio?error")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/loginValidation")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")            
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/inicio?logout")
            .permitAll()
        ;       
    }

}
```

**La información en Base de datos es la siguiente:**

```
select U.username, P.name, M.url from user U
join profile P on P.id=U.profile_id
join profile_menu  PM on PM.profile_id=P.id
join menu M on M.id=PM.menu_id
```

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

**Finalmente en el controlador tengo las siguientes rutas, y  quiero por ejemplo que ducho usuario no tenga acceso a la ruta noAdministrador o a cualquiero otra que no este registrada en en base de datos**

```
package com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.controller;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.configuration.EscuelappProperties;
import com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.entity.User;
import com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.model.CustomUserDetail;
import com.escuelaapp.EscuelaApp.model.LoggedUser;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(LoginController.class);

    @Autowired
    EscuelappProperties properties;  

    @GetMapping({"/inicio","/"})
    public String index(Model model,@RequestParam(required=false) String error, @RequestParam(required=false) String logout) {
        properties.initSliders();
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("prop", properties);
        model.addAttribute("error", error);
        model.addAttribute("logout", logout);
        return "index";
        //return "redirect:/login";
    }   


    @GetMapping("/dashboard")
    public ModelAndView dashboard() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard");
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
         //LoggedUser principal = (LoggedUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
         //CustomUserDetail principal = (CustomUserDetail) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().toString());
         //User user = principal.getUser();     
        //mav.addObject("user", user);
        mav.addObject("username", user.getUsername());
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("/usuarios")
    public @ResponseBody String usuarios() {
        return "Tiene acceso a la ruta:  usuarios";
    }

    @GetMapping("/permisos")
    public @ResponseBody String permisos() {
        return "Tiene acceso a la ruta:  permisos";
    }   

    @GetMapping("/noAdministrador")
    public @ResponseBody String noAdmin() {
        return "Tiene acceso a la ruta:  no Admin";
    }   


}
```

**Agradezco su colaboración en relación a la información que me puedan aportar para comprender como es que funciona Spring Security o si es que esta validación de permisos por perfiles o roles tengo que hacerla de forma manual.**

Answer (score 2):

Estoy basandome en estos articulos de Baeldung: ["Role and Privilege for Spring Security registration"](https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration) y ["Spring Security Granted Authority vs Role"](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-granted-authority-vs-role). Para mayor detalle puedes referenciar este [proyecto de Github](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration).

Primero necesitaras tener 3 Objetos de Entidad que corresponden a las tablas de Usuario, Rol y Permiso en tu base de datos:

[Modelo de Usuario](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/persistence/model/User.java):

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean tokenExpired;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "users_roles", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
    private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

[Modelo de Rol](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/persistence/model/Role.java):

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "roles_privileges", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;   
}
```

[Modelo de Permiso](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/persistence/model/Privilege.java):

```
@Entity
public class Privilege {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

Una vez tengas las entidades, procedemos a crear un componente que inicializa la base de datos con los permisos y roles validos (esto es totalmente opcional, puedes configurarlo directamente desde la BD sin hacer uso de esto):

```
@Component
public class InitialDataLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    boolean alreadySetup = false;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        // Verificamos que no se haya realizado la inicializacion previamente
        if (alreadySetup) {
            return;
        }

        // Aqui se deben crear los permisos
        Privilege readPrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("PERMISO_LECTURA");
        Privilege writePrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("PERMISO_ESCRITURA");
        Privilege otherPrivilege = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("PERMISO_OTRO");

        //Asociamos los permisos a roles
        List<Privilege> adminPrivileges = Arrays.asList(readPrivilege, writePrivilege, otherPrivilege);        
        Role adminRole = createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_ADMIN", adminPrivileges);

        List<Privilege> userPrivileges = Arrays.asList(readPrivilege, otherPrivilege);
        Role userRole = createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_USUARIO", Arrays.asList(userPrivileges));

        // Creamos un usuario Test con rol Admin
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Test");
        user.setLastName("Test");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("test"));
        user.setEmail("test@test.com");
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(adminRole));
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(user);

        alreadySetup = true;
    }

    @Transactional
    private Privilege createPrivilegeIfNotFound(String name) {

        Privilege privilege = privilegeRepository.findByName(name);
        if (privilege == null) {
            privilege = new Privilege(name);
            return privilegeRepository.save(privilege);
        }
        return privilege;
    }

    @Transactional
    private Role createRoleIfNotFound(String name, Collection<Privilege> privileges) {

        Role role = roleRepository.findByName(name);
        if (role == null) {
            role = new Role(name);
            role.setPrivileges(privileges);
            return roleRepository.save(role);
        }
        return role;
    }
}
```

Ojo, con respecto a lo anterior:

1. En Spring, normalmente a lo que nosotros nos hemos referido como `Permiso` (`Privilege`), ellos le denominan `Role` o `(Granted) Authority`
2. Se debe el usar el prefijo `ROLE`  cuando definimos nombres roles (O almenos en versiones previas a Spring Security 4). Naturalmente esto puede ser cambiado con configuraciones de Spring.

Ya teniendo lo anterior, el archivo de configuracion de seguridad (que en este caso extiende de `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) puede ser editado de la siguiente manera:

[Security Config](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/spring/SecSecurityConfig.java)

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
///...

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ///...

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    ///...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       // ...
       .antMatchers("/protegido-por-role").hasRole("ROLE_USUARIO")
       .antMatchers("/protegido-por-authority").hasAuthority("PERMISO_LECTURA")
       // ...
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        final CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(CustomUserDetailsService);
        // ...
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

Como podras ver se configuran roles y permisos asignados a rutas individuales.
A su vez, se debe especificar un Bean de tipo `DaoAuthenticationProvider` que indique que sevicio (`UserDetailsService`) debe usar para autenticar y obtener la informacion del usuario que esta logeado en este momento.

[Servicio de Detalles de Usuario](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/security/MyUserDetailsService.java):

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IUserService service;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messages;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No se encontre el usuario con email: " + email);
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = getAuthorities(user.getRoles());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
          user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, grantedAuthorities);
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
        return getGrantedAuthorities(getPrivileges(roles));
    }

    private List<String> getPrivileges(Collection<Role> roles) {

        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Privilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Role role : roles) {
            collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
        }
        for (Privilege item : collection) {
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String privilege : privileges) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

En breve el proveedor debe efectual alguna logica para determinar si las credenciales proveidas por el usuario son validas.

[Proveedor de Autenticacion](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/security/google2fa/CustomAuthenticationProvider.java):

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        final User user = userRepository.findByEmail(auth.getName());
        if ((user == null)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
        }

        // logica que autentica al usuario ...

        final Authentication result = super.authenticate(auth);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, result.getCredentials(), result.getAuthorities());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Por lo que he visto tu codigo, tienes algo muy similar. Creo que jugando un poco con esto y los ejemplos en los que me base podras logar lo que necesitas =)

Comment: Muchs gracias por tu tiempo, en efecto he podido dar con el chiste!

Comment: En ese caso, puedes aceptar mi respuesta como una solucion valida a tu problema ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar mi problema, he configurado el rol como un Authority, incluyendo el prefijo ROLE_

```
@Service("UserServiceSecurity")
public class UserServiceSecurity implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("UserRepository")
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX+user.getProfile().getName()));
        user.getProfile().getProfileMenus().stream().forEach((x) -> {
            auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(x.getMenus().getUrl()));
        });
        return userBuiler(user, auths);
    }

    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userBuiler(User user,
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
                authorities);
    }
}
```

Y luego añadí add @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLENAME')") en un controllador o metodo Controller o method:

```
@Controller

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('DOCENTE')")
@RequestMapping("/docente")
public class TeacherController {

    //@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('/docente/registrar-asistencia')")
    @GetMapping("/registrar-asistencia")
    public @ResponseBody String registrarAsistencia() {
        return "Tiene acceso a la ruta:  registrarAsistencia";
    }

    @GetMapping("/generar-boletin")
    public @ResponseBody String generarBoletin() {
        return "Tiene acceso a la ruta:  generar-boletin";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

para restringir que ciertos usuarios no puedan ejecutar algunas tareas debes de hacer lo siguiente. El @Secured te permite definir quien tiene acceso a dicho método colocando sus roles respectivos. Saludos!

```
//filtrar Area Usuaria
    @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER","ROLE_USERGESTSERV","ROLE_USERGESTSERV2"})
    @GetMapping("/listFindAre") 
    public String listFindAre(Model model) {
        try {
            model.addAttribute("contrato", new Contrato());
            //Listar proveedores no repetidos y ordenados
            List<Contrato> listaConDuplicados = cService.findAll();
            List<String> listaSinDuplicados = listaConDuplicados.stream()
                      .map(item->item.getAg_area_usuario_con())
                      .distinct()
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
             Collections.sort(listaSinDuplicados);
            model.addAttribute("listaContratos2", listaSinDuplicados);
            //
        } catch (Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return "/contrato/findAre";
    }
```